# QR code readable by specific device?

Tags: security, qr-code

Does exist a way to make a QR code readable by only a certain device with a code that matches a specific information contained in the QR?

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt the contents of the QR code with a key that only your reader can understand?

Comment: Yes, but it won't be able to understand it. Is that not what you need? Are you asking if it is possible to create your own unique style of QR Code?